# JavaScript Timelog class

Tags: javascript, web

I have a problem with this code

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDay();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

window.onload = init;
function init() {
    document.timelog.currentYear.options[new Date().getFullYear() - 1999].selected = true;
    document.timelog.month.options[new Date().getMonth()].selected = true;
    document.timelog.day.options[new Date().getDate() - 1].selected = true;

}
```

I understand what's going wrong, where it says document.timelog.currentYear, currentYear is the id of a dropdown box but I do not know how to fix this

Please Help

Update

Here is a the HTML

```
<select class="form-control inputBox dateBox dayBox day" style="width: 68px" id="day" name="day">
                        <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
                        <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
                        <option value="3" selected="">3</option>
                        <option value="4" selected="">4</option>
                        <option value="5" selected="">5</option>
                        <option value="6" selected="">6</option>
                        <option value="7" selected="">7</option>
                        <option value="8" selected="">8</option>
                        <option value="9" selected="">9</option>
                        <option value="10" selected="">10</option>
                        <option value="11" selected="">11</option>
                        <option value="12" selected="">12</option>
                        <option value="13" selected="">13</option>
                        <option value="14" selected="">14</option>
                        <option value="15" selected="">15</option>
                        <option value="16" selected="">16</option>
                        <option value="17" selected="">17</option>
                        <option value="18" selected="">18</option>
                        <option value="19" selected="">19</option>
                        <option value="20" selected="">20</option>
                        <option value="21" selected="">21</option>
                        <option value="22" selected="">22</option>
                        <option value="23" selected="">23</option>
                        <option value="24" selected="">24</option>
                        <option value="25" selected="">25</option>
                        <option value="26" selected="">26</option>
                        <option value="27" selected="">27</option>
                        <option value="28" selected="">28</option>
                        <option value="29" selected="">29</option>
                        <option value="30" selected="">30</option>
                        <option value="31" selected="">31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-control inputBox dateBox month" style="width: 81px" id="month" name="month">
                        <option value="1" selected="">Jan</option>
                        <option value="2" selected="">Feb</option>
                        <option value="3" selected="">Mar</option>
                        <option value="4" selected="">Apr</option>
                        <option value="5" selected="">May</option>
                        <option value="6" selected="">Jun</option>
                        <option value="7" selected="">Jul</option>
                        <option value="8" selected="">Aug</option>
                        <option value="9" selected="">Sep</option>
                        <option value="10" selected="">Oct</option>
                        <option value="11" selected="">Nov</option>
                        <option value="12" selected="">Dec</option>
                    </select>
                    <select class="form-control inputBox dateBox currentYear" style="width: 84px" id="currentYear" name="currentYear">
                        <option value="1999" selected="">1999</option>
                        <option value="2000" selected="">2000</option>
                        <option value="2001" selected="">2001</option>
                        <option value="2002" selected="">2002</option>
                        <option value="2003" selected="">2003</option>
                        <option value="2004" selected="">2004</option>
                        <option value="2005" selected="">2005</option>
                        <option value="2006" selected="">2006</option>
                        <option value="2007" selected="">2007</option>
                        <option value="2008" selected="">2008</option>
                        <option value="2009" selected="">2009</option>
                        <option value="2010" selected="">2010</option>
                        <option value="2011" selected="">2011</option>
                        <option value="2012" selected="">2012</option>
                        <option value="2013" selected="">2013</option>
                        <option value="2014" selected="">2014</option>
                        <option value="2015" selected="">2015</option>
                        <option value="2016" selected="">2016</option>
                    </select>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your end result is meant to be to me, could you explain what you are trying to do do?

Comment: I am trying to get the date and input it into 3 separate dropdown boxes

Comment: @JakeLambourn question is not clear , would you provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelambourn/S2ubK/1/#&togetherjs=oMmxsP3S6x

Comment: Basically I want todays date in the 3 dropdown boxes one for day, one for month, one for year

Comment: don't worry I have fixed this using jQuery

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    
    window.onload = init;
    function init() {
     $("#currentYear").val(y);
     $("#month").val(m);
     $("#day").val(d);    
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't worry I have fixed this using jQuery

```
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
var y = date.getFullYear();

window.onload = init;
function init() {
    $("#currentYear").val(y);
    $("#month").val(m);
    $("#day").val(d);    
}
```